# Why do web pages break the layout if the zoom is increased?

Tags: html, layout, web

Why do some web pages break the layout when the zoom is increased on them? In my understanding of web pages and browsers the only thing that should happen is that everything is "expanded" ... but things should not relocate to any other place, just ... grow.

Is this a browser issue or a web page issue? Can anyone give a more clear explanation?

A very good example of this is stackoverflow.com (using firefox 30.0 on ubuntu 14.04):

Zoom at 100%:
[image]

Zoom at 120%:
[image]

Comment: @chiapa The "Top Qeustions" text is much more to the left on the 120% zoom than on the 100% .

Comment: I saw that, and erased my comment. Well, with which browser did that happen? I've tried with IE, FF and Chrome and that never happened

Comment: As mentioned in the question: firefox 30.0

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I can't help as I'm using Firefox 30.0 and that's not occurring here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have configured your copy of Firefox to "Zoom Text Only" (from the View menu).

This increases the font size without increasing the size of elements defined with pixel based heights / widths.

Comment: Yess! That's amazing! I don't really use the menu so it was sort of forgotten for a long time  :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this problem. Please check again after unchecking Zoom Text Only in the View menu. credits : [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin)

---

As far as answering your actual question, in the earlier days of website programming, most types of screen sizes or resolutions were fixed. So the developers used to hard-code the values and sizes of **SOME** of the elements with respect to the page. But when you zoomed in, thereby changing the apparent size of the page in the browser, some of those elements tried to keep their old values and some did not, which led to the distorted looking pages.

Nowadays, with what we call as responsive web design, all the element sizes are designed for various screen sizes and since zooming in changes the apparent size of the page, they readjust their layout.